# React Console Warning "No routes matched location"

Tags: reactjs, url-routing

I'm developing a web application that retrieves data from a Python Flask API and displays it using React on the frontend.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I initially access [http://localhost:3000/], I see a blank page with a console warning stating,

> "No routes matched location "/"

I've defined routes in my App.js to redirect to the Dashboard once the user is authenticated successfully, and that part is functioning correctly. Interestingly, when I access http://localhost:3000/login, it works as expected and redirects to the Dashboard after successful authentication.

**App.js code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';


function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={
            <Login setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          element={<Dashboard />}
        />
        <Route element ={<Navigate to ="/login" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default App;
```

**Login.js code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
  const Navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const initiateAuthorization = () => {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/authorize";
  };

//   const handleAuthentication = () => {
//     setTimeout(() => {
//       setIsAuthenticated(true);
//       Navigate.push("/dashboard");
//     }, 2000);
//   };
//   useEffect(() => {
//     setIsAuthenticated(true);
//     Navigate.push("/dashboard");
//   }, []);
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <h2>Login to Actionstep</h2>
      <button onClick={initiateAuthorization}>
        Authorize with Actionstep
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    function Dashboard() {
      const [actionCount, setActiveActionCount] = useState({ active: 0, closed: 0 });
      const [taskCount, setTaskCount] = useState({ complete: 0, incomplete: 0, overdue: 0 });
      const [actionTypeCount, setactionTypeCount] = useState({});
      const [participantMap, setTaskAssignee] = useState({});
      // const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false); // Track if the user is authorized
    
      useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchActiveActionCount() {
          try { }
    
        fetchActiveActionCount();
      }, []);
    
    }
    
    export default Dashboard;
```

My goal is to display the login screen when I access http://localhost:3000/. Can anyone assist me in achieving this?

Comment: You didn't declare route with path `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a path for route "/" like this:

```
<Route
      path="/"
      element={
        <Login setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} />
      }
    />
```